# iPod: podcasts not syncing

Tags: windows-vista, audio, sync, ipod, podcasts

I have a 5G 80Gb iPod, iTunes 8.2.1.6 & Windows Vista.

I have subscribed to video podcasts and these sync no problem to my iPod. I have then subscribed to audio podcasts but these are not syncing. They are correctly present in my podcast folder on my harddrive - they just don't go to the iPod.

Any ideas?

They do play back in iTunes and Windows Media Player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Under Devices, click on your Phone/iPod in the left pane.
2. Click on Podcasts in the right pane (between TV Shows and Books).
3. Make sure that all your podcasts are checked.

Comment: Yeah, that was it, thanks! For clarification: **Devices** is shown in the left pane when the iPod is plugged in.